# Multiple Views OnTouch Events

Tags: android

We are developing an application where we need to capture MotionEvents from multiple views simultaneously. When we try to do so, Android only dispatches events to the first touched view and, when touching another view simultaneously, it gives us an ACTION_POINTER_DOWN on the first view only, even if the pointer coordinates are outside its bounds and inside the other views'.

Is there any way we can get events dispatched to every touched view (in separate calls to OnTouch)?

We believe intercepting the touch events from a parent view and then manually dispatching them to each view might work, but even if it does, it would not be practical for what we are trying to achieve. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 10):

At least Android 3.0 adds support for splitting touch events between multiple Views.

Split touch events is enabled by default when AndroidManifest `<uses-sdk>` defines either `android:minSdkVersion="11"` or `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`. For explanation See [android:splitMotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#splitMotionEvents) and [android:windowEnableSplitTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnableSplitTouch)

Answer (score 6):

Touch event is first catched by the view currently in focus. If you touched 1 view and have "consumed" event and are working with it, any other events will be dispatched to this view, no matter where you click.

If you return false from your touchListener (thus saying that event is not consumed) it will be delegated down to other views, but on another separate click new event will be dispatched to other view.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-3-understanding-touch-events/1775

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: I am having the same problem, i.e. the focused view is moved if I touch anywhere left on the screen, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

While this should work automatically with Android SDK 11+, it wasn't working for my app. I was trying to capture touches in a main view, plus some views that were subviews of the main view; in that case, touches were only captured by the view "level" that received the first touch. I reorganized my view structure so that all the views were siblings and now they are capturing events as expected.